# Настройка ejabberd_xmlrpc

Tags: erlang, xmpp

Задача: Написать приложение на любом языке разработки, которое могло бы регистрировать пользователя ejabberd и заносить его в определенную shared roster group.

Решение в теории: Погуглив пришел к надстройке xmlrpc jabber xml rpc. Она требует соответствующего мода для ejabberd (ejabberd_xmlrpc) который слушает порт 4560 и обрабатывает внешние запросы, которые мы можем сделать посредством curl.

Проблема: Мод казалось бы нативный, все раскоменчено, при запросе на Ip сервера и порт 4560 всегда "400 Bad request", при запросе через curl, допустим на создание юзера, видим беспрестанно Error -118 Unautorized request.

Данные: Порт слушается правильно, поскольку в браузере видим ответ от ерланг веб-сервера, ejabberd версия 15,07 установленная из докер репозитория (https://github.com/rroemhild/docker-ejabberd). Также показываю кусочек ejabberd.yml:

```
listen:
  -
    port: 5222
    module: ejabberd_c2s
    starttls_required: true

    protocol_options:
      - "no_sslv3"
      - "no_tlsv1"
    max_stanza_size: 65536
    shaper: c2s_shaper
    access: c2s
  -
    port: 5269
    module: ejabberd_s2s_in
  -
    port: 4560
    module: ejabberd_xmlrpc
    access_commands:
      configure:
        all: []
```

в /lib/ejabberd/ebeans/ файл ejabberd_xmlrpc.bean присутствует.

Comment: *Unautorized request* — вероятно, требуется аутентификация при выполнении запроса. [примеры](https://www.ejabberd.im/ejabberd_xmlrpc) смотрели?

Comment: Да негде там авторизовываться, да и ошибка говорит о том что неавторизованный запрос, что скорее всего ведет к тому, что нужно где-то составить список разрешенных запросов, примеры все для cfg, Для .yml примеров, увы не нашел.